# What header do I have to include to write Hangeul out to a console window using Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, unicode, console, char

First, briefly,
My computer with Window11OS showed this console window.

> ?? ? ?? C++????
> C:\Users\MYNAME\source\repos\20220816ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\20220816ConsoleApplication1.exe (process 17604) exited with code 0.

and quetionmarks are NOT what I intended.

I think I need to use intentionally UNICODE here.
But I don't know how to do, I failed once; I'll explain later.

So, this is the code that I want to fix. And I'm using Visual Studio as Windows Console Application(C++/WInRT) for this solution-file.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
using namespace std;
/*표준 출력 스트림으로 문장을 출력함
근데 왜 한글이 물음표로 나올까*/
cout << "나의 첫 번째 C++프로그램" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

But VS's error-list showed me the below.

> Warning    C4566   character represented by universal-character-name '\uB098' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)

What property I've changed to build successfully was the below

> VS's upper menu > Project > Properties(the lowest item) > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers > Precompiled Header : Use(/Yu) --I CHANGED IT TO-->> Not Using Precompiled Headers

I also had tried to change "Language" property just like the screenshot below, but I had failed to build at all, even question-marks hadn't shown.
[What I had tried to show Hangeul-language instead of question-marks  but failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unfMy.png)

Comment: Understand that there are two different problems here. How to represent Hangeul characters in your **source code**, and how to get Hanguel characters printed in the **console**. Unfortunately I'm not confident with the answer to either of these questions.

Comment: Using `wcout << L"나의 첫 번째 C++프로그램" << endl;` (notice the extra `w` and `L`) solves the first problem (for me) but did not solve the second problem. But things might be different for you.

Comment: Have you tried `std::cout.imbue(std::locale("korean"));` before calling `std::cout`?

Comment: I tried your latest suggestion, but VS still warns me for the same reason... "Warning C4566 character represented by universal-character-name '\uBC88' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252) 20220816C++1st8page,FirstStep"

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, use the following to set the console stdout to Unicode mode.  Save the file with UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding, or UTF-8 without BOM and compile with the `/utf-8` switch.  You Windows needs to support the Korean language or at least use a console font that supports Korean characters such as NSimSun.

**test.cpp**: compiled with "cl /W4 /EHsc /utf-8 test.cpp"

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wcout << L"나의 첫 번째 C++프로그램" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output (cut/paste from cmd window):

```
나의 첫 번째 C++프로그램
```

Comment: Thank you. The code worked at my laptop. I think I should search for NSimSun.

Comment: @Snowflake NSimSun comes with Windows if you install Chinese (and probably Korean) language support.  I have Chinese support installed, but Korean is supported by the font as well.  Go to Language Settings and in Preferred Language click "Add a language"

Comment: I've just tried to install Korean to VisualStudio thru VisualStudioInstaller, then I've changed it to Korean and built the previous my-source-code, it doesn't work, still shows me question-marks instead of Korean-char-console-out. Only thing that has changed is all the language for menus on the IDE-screen. Hoh... This is not the reason to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for NSimSun-solution. I changed my font to this, at Options/Environment/Fonts and colors/Display items.

Comment: @Snowflake Instsll Korean language support in Windows itself, not VS. You don’t have to make it the default language, but you get the font and input method editor support to type and view Korean.  Then in the console you can select a font such as NSimSun, or change to a Korean code page via `chcp` command.